# Element with display: none still visible?

Tags: html, css

Why is the icon still visible even with display: none?

```css
.toc.item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <a class="toc item"><i class="sidebar icon"></i></a>
```

Comment: your CSS is not properly link to your document or another rule overwrite this one. As it is here it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @GCyrillus I want to suggest right clicking the icon and choose "inspect element" in the browser. Look for your code. If it's striked through something else is overwriting your code. Search for a display that's not striked through to see what is messing it up. If you can't find your code the css file is not properly linked.

If you're having trouble overriding the code that's overriding yours in the first place, you might want to add `!important` to your code.

```
display: none !important;
```